# why std::future template argument type is reference type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am looking at the `std::future` documentation at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future

What I don't understand is that why the template argument type(in `2`) is `reference`?

> ```
> template< class T > class future<T&>; (2) (since C++11)
> ```

Comment: It's a partial specialization for reference types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reference specialization for `std::future` which accounts for those cases in which the return values is a reference type.

Check for instance the following example code:

```
// future example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <future>         // std::async, std::future


int counter = 0;

int& increment_counter()
{
    return ++counter;
}

int main ()
{
    std::future<int&> fut = std::async(increment_counter); 

    int &counterRef = fut.get();

    std::cout << "value:" << counterRef << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```